# Laravel 5 VueJS not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use vuejs in my fresh laravel setup. I run the follwing commands in my command line

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

This commands runs without any errors. When I import the default VUE componet located under `~/ressources/assets/components/ExampleComponent.vue` in my template nothing happends.

```
@section('content')
    <example-component></example-component>
@endsection
```

Here the app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: What's inside ExampleComponent that is not working?

Comment: The defult content from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using Laravel Mix  check your webpack.mix.js file, default config must look like this

```
 mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Now, look if you have linked JS file to you blade template

Looks like this for older Laravel versions (<= 5.5):

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

and like this for new once  (> 5.5)

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Finally, see you have

```
el: '#app'
```

it mean  # - id, like in CSS, VueJS will search for element with id app.
Everything outside that element will not work.

so you have to use it like

```
<div id='app'> 
<example-component></example-component>
</div>
```

or

```
<section id='app'> 
    <example-component></example-component>
    </section>
```

Comment: **Laravel 5.7**: `assets` is gone, as per: [https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-7-resources-directory-changes]

Answer (score 2):

I think you should wrap the container div with an id of app

```
<div id="app" > <example-component></example-component> </div>
```

if not just check if the Js files are properly imported in the php file

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem and mine is solved. I'm not importing

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

check that you are importing `js/app.js` and `#app`

It should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Lol, it was an faceplam question. I've removed the `@yield('content')` from the layout file. Sorry for that and tanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

check if you are importing app.js

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```