# ExampleComponent.vue is not working Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-7

I tried lot of ways to fix this problem from stackoverflow, laracast, google but nothing works,

-> I think my **vue.js is not loading or working**(Im using sublime text, all files showing *highlighted or colored text except ExampleCmponent.vue file*), **npm run watch** successfully but vue devtools also not deteceting any vue.

-> I also tried:

```
<div id="app">
     <example-component></example-component>
 </div>
```

Im sharing screenshots with you please help me out if possible:
**ExampleComponent.vue**

[image: ExampleComponent.vue]

**home.blade**: i also tried without #id tag->

[image: home.blade]

chrome:***vue devtools***:

[image]

here is **app.js**:

[image: app.js]

I tried:

[Laravel 5 VueJS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088957/laravel-5-vuejs-not-working)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/example-component-not-working

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done here is called [Fronend-Scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend). You still need to [Compile Assets](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix).

Open your **webpack.mix.js** and add your **.js** & **.scss** files. Once done, confirm files are in public /js /css folder.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Then, add below lines in your blade.

```
// use mix() for cache bursting. Or simply stick with asset()
<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```